# In jmeter how to send post request with csrf token name and value changing on each iteration

Tags: jmeter

I tried extracting name and value of token using regular expression and use it in post call with the defined variables but the call keeps on failing.
Below is the html code :

```
<input type="hidden" name="e4662291f0b8" value="b9cd1ccb0e33594426209c9bea2392fb04d4b54529780a63d4a538c74f852674"/>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: I was able to make it work using HTTP cookie manager. Thanks anyways!